# Does my racial +2 str bonus apply to my synthesist eidolon stat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ability-scores, eidolon

I am starting a synthesis eidolon character with natural weapons and grapple build — I initially chose a Suli with a +2 Str for a bloodrager and then changed my class.  The Suli's elemental assault still works well with extra damage.  Can I apply my racial +2 str bonus to my synthesist eidolon stat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found the answer.  Not what I wanted to hear:

> #### [Fused Eidolon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/archetypes/paizo---summoner-archetypes/synthesist)
>
> While fused with his eidolon, the synthesist uses the eidolon’s physical ability scores (Strength, Dexterity, and Constitution), but retains his own mental ability scores (Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma).

I was hoping to have that +2 str racial bonus do me some good instead of being replaced by the eidolon's.  I had a really decent stat roll = 17, 16, 16, 16, 15, 13.  So I guess I will just put the 13 in the summoner's Str - it will be boosted to 15 and still qualifies for power attack and benefits my carrying capacity.

Comment: The answer you found is, as far as I know, correct. You should ask a new question about optimizing your character.

Comment: This site works quite a bit differently from discussion forums you might be familiar with, since it focuses on strict Q&A instead of discussion threads. (See the [tour] and [help] for more on that.) Part of that is that answer posts are only for answering the question, so I've removed the new question from this answer. If you have a new question, just ask a new question in a fresh question post. Thanks!